# Is the "product topology" a topology?

Tags: general-topology

The question is

> Let $(\Omega_1,\tau_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,\tau_2)$ be two topological spaces, then is $\left( {{{{\Omega }}_1} \times {{{\Omega }}_2},\tau} \right)$ where $\tau=\{A\times B:A\in \tau_1,B\in \tau_2\}$ also a topological space?

I was trying to prove the claim but was not successful.

1. $\emptyset  \times \emptyset  = \emptyset  \in {\tau _1} \times {\tau _2}$; $Ω_1×Ω_2∈τ_1×τ_2$.
2. Given finitely many $A_1,A_2,…,A_n\in\tau$, then each $A_k=U_k\times V_k$ where $U_k∈τ_1,V_k∈τ_2$ for each $k=1,2,…,n$. Then $⋂_{k=1}^nA_k=⋂_{k=1}^n(U_k×V_k)=(⋂_{k=1}^nU_k )×(⋂_{k=1}^nV_k) ∈τ_1×τ_2$. To see the last equality, check $(x,y)∈⋂_{k=1}^nU_k×V_k⟺(x,y)∈U_k×V_k⟺x∈U_k,y∈V_k$ for every $k ⟺x∈⋂_{k=1}^nU_k ,y∈⋂_{k=1}^nV_k ⟺(x,y)∈(⋂_{k=1}^nU_k ×⋂_{k=1}^nV_k )$.
3. However, I got a problem for union. Given a family of sets $\{A_k \}_{k∈J}$, then each $A_k=U_k×V_k$ where $U_k∈τ_1,V_k∈τ_2$ for each $k∈J$. Then $⋃A_k =⋃(U_k×V_k)$. **I get stuck here** since we only have $⋃(U_k×V_k)\subseteq(⋃U_k)\times (⋃V_k)$ rather than equality.

I now doubt the claim might be false.

Can anyone help with 3) or give a counterexample? Thank you!

Comment: There's an awful lot of notation here.

Comment: This is a strange question. On its face, the claim seems to be false. But maybe it's just using weird notation. What is the author's definition of a topological space $(\Omega, \tau)$, and what is their definition of $\tau_1\times\tau_2$?

Comment: This exercise would make more sense if the "basic open neighborhoods" definition of a topology were being used to qualify $\tau_1,\tau_2$.  If $\tau_1$ is a system of basic open neighborhoods in the topology on $\Omega_1$ and $\tau_2$ is a system of basic open neighborhoods in the topology on $\Omega_2$, then sure enough the products of pairs of basic open neighborhoods $\mathcal{O}_1\times \mathcal{O}_2$ form a system of basic open neighborhoods for the product topology.  Now this isn't quite the same as $\tau_1\times \tau_2$, but you seem resigned to a bit of liberal interpretation.

Comment: To address the edit: No, $\tau_1\times\tau_2$ cannot mean the Cartesian product of the collections $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, because an element of the Cartesian product would be an ordered pair, not a product of sets itself. Please just quote the problem statement. Where does the problem come from?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have refined the question.

Comment: @Tony, could you please clarify where the question comes from? Is it a question that you personally invented and are curious about, or are you translating it from an external source...?

Comment: @ChrisCulter This is an exercise. At the beginning I thought it was true when I proved the first two topology axioms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, we lose it in the union. Think of the open unit ball $\Bbb R^2$. If we had equality in your third statement, it would have to be an open square (in other words, not every open set can be written as $A\times B$ for $A\in\tau_1$ and $B\in \tau_2$). What you *can* say is that $\tau$ as it is defined in the original post forms a basis for a topology.

Answer (score 4):

The statement is false in general. $\tau$ is the basis for a topology on $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$, but is not a full topology itself. To see this, let both spaces be $\Bbb R$, and ask, is the open ball in $\tau$?

Comment: Awe man! beat by 24 seconds. And it was only because Math Exchange decided to make me prove I was human!

Comment: Haha, nice answer, though! :)

Comment: @PaulSinclair Well, are you?

Comment: maybe he isn't but he passed the Turing test.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Hi. Thank you for your answer. I agree the claim should be false but I am a little confused about the counterexample you give. I am not sure, but I think probably we need to find some sets in $\tau$ whose union is not in $\tau$? I agree open balls are not in $\tau$, but how do I show an open ball is an union of some other sets in $\tau$? Thank you!

Comment: @Tony: A picture can go a long ways toward convincing you that you can fill the circle with smaller and smaller rectangles. More formally, for each point in the open unit ball, try to construct a rectangle around it (similar to constructing another open ball around it).

Comment: @Clayton Thank you for clarification. I recall from real analysis that every open set in $\Bbb {R}^n$ is a countable union of non-overlapping closed cubes, but they are closed, not open. So an open ball can also be expressed as a union of open rectangles?

Comment: @Tony: Correct! In real analysis, the motivation there was for non-overlapping (so the volume of the union was just the sum of the volumes of each cube together). In topology, we're not so interested in the volume.